# Change order of the table rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a table in PostgreSQL. I want to re-order the rows data physically according to a specific column (which is not primary key). In my case this column type is `date`. How can I do it?

Comment: use an `order by` when selecting the data.

Comment: I want to update the table itself, how can it help me?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, in the end some order will be shown and usually it does not change. I want to change the appearance.

Comment: Again: the rows are ***NOT*** ordered. And even if you get them into some "order", that would be futile because changes to the table will change the phyiscal location of the rows. And it's not guaranteed that a select will actually return the rows in the based on the physical location. What you are asking makes no sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - reorder in place seems to be useful to utilize new BRIN feature in 9.5, the question is still valid IMO.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it benefits from data being ordered, at least according to developers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0xHOPXZq9g

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and what about other cases where already it could be applied? You have a static unordered big dataset on which you are going to run high number of queries, which could benefit from BRIN. Currently you need to *create table as select ... order by idx_col*. User has a good rationale to look for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 32):

If you have an index on that column, then the `CLUSTER` command will physically "order" the rows according to that index

```
CLUSTER [VERBOSE] table_name [ USING index_name ]
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html

Note that this "order" isn't automatically maintained, you need to run that statement on a regular basis manually.

---

This will however ***not*** guarantee any specific order when retrieving the rows. Not even when no joins or aggregates are involved.

Even if all you do is `select * from the_table` the order in which the rows are returned is still not guaranteed. For example: Postgres has a feature called "synchronized seq scan", which means that if one session starts a seq scan (`select * from ...`) and another session is doing the same thing, the second one piggy-backs on the first seq scan (where ever that is) and then adds the "missed" rows at the end of the result.

The ***only*** way to guarantee an order of a result set (really: the **only**) is to supply an `order by` clause.

---

This only makes sense (at least to me) if you have a **single** harddisk in your server (which is *not* a SSD). In that case a seq scan *might* be faster because all blocks *might* be right next to each other (which isn't guaranteed either because of the way a file system re-uses free space).

On a SSD or a proper server which uses a RAID array with many, many hard disks I can't see how this could be beneficial in any way.

Comment: Isn't that somewhere on the postgres roadmap of future releases? some of the others db allows user to cluster index table, this would be even more useful for temporal queries where order of rows matter most.

Comment: @jangorecki: I'm not aware of any such change. And I still don't think this is really _that_ useful given that any serious DB server will use many harddisks (potentially hundreds) - how do you define the "order" in that case? And random access on a SSD has no overhead anyway

Comment: Let's say I have a BRIN index and I'm using `CLUSTER` to physically reorder the rows in order to better fit the index, won't reordering break my index or is it updated along with the `CLUSTER` operation? I guess what I'm trying to say, shouldn't it be the other way round in order for BRIN to work best: reorder, then create the index. And how would one accomplish that?

Comment: Doesn't a DB retrieve data in chunks/blocks/pages (where each chunk may include more data than requested)?  And if you need to use contiguous data, wouldn't clustering it help prevent loading of additional chunks?

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried "ORDER BY"?  For example, "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY date ASC;"?  If you want the dates in reverse order, you can try "DESC" instead of "ASC".

Comment: That's retrieving data in order. Nothing to do with sorting.