# After Inserting through a select statement Redshift records are not in order

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to populate a date dimension table in Redshift.

I can able to populate by this query .

```
insert into date_dimension ..
....................
select ......   
 from 
  (
    SELECT
      '2020-12-31' :: DATE + seq AS datum,
      seq
    FROM (SELECT row_number() over () AS seq FROM stl_scan LIMIT 365 ) 
    ORDER BY seq
  )
```

But the data populated is not in order while selecting . like below example

[image]

If I am doing an Order by then data is correct . This is seems odd. Why is this this happening ?

Comment: you have to mention the condition for the records to be ordered in your inner query. The condition can be `row_number() over (order by day_of_week_nbr desc) as seq` .

Comment: Physical on-disk order is not guaranteed unless the table is [clustered](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-cluster.html#:~:text=When%20a%20table%20is%20clustered%2C%20it%20is%20physically%20reordered%20based%20on%20the%20index%20information). `select` read order can also differ from the physical order in db pages. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175992/change-order-of-the-table-rows-in-postgresql) is a similar thread. Typically, if you require a certain order of rows from your `select` statement, you need an `order by`.

Comment: Tables in an RDBMS represent unordered sets - you do not order when you insert data, you order when you query data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've edited my comment to clarify that, right after posting. The top answer in the linked thread also points it out.